# MySQL query to print data from two tables

Tags: mysql

[image]

I need help with writing a MySQL query to print the respective department names and number of `Employee` for all departments in the `Department` table.

Expected output:

```
Executive 2
Technical 2
Production 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A `join` command would be what you are looking for.

```
select transaction.username, transaction.transactiondate, products.price, products.quantity, products.description
from transaction, products
where products.productid = transaction.productid
  and products.productid = IDHERE
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a simple table which structure as below show:

```
+--------+------+
| name   | dep  |
+--------+------+
| frank  | IT   |
| jack   | IT   |
| Sissel | FA   |
| Li     | FA   |
| Mok    | PM   |
+--------+------+
```

You have three department maybe more, you can simple use `count` to fetch number of employee for all departments. and if you use `group by dep` you will get each number by you expect .

```
SELECT dep, count(*) FROM user_table GROUP BY dep;
```

And then you got:

```
+------+----------+
| dep  | count(*) |
+------+----------+
| FA   |        2 |
| IT   |        2 |
| PM   |        1 |
+------+----------+
```

Hope, that's all your need~

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name as department_name, count(b.id) as num_of_employees
FROM department a INNER JOIN employee b ON a.dept_id = b.dept_id
GROUP BY a.dept_id
```